# Difficulties Creating Popup Javascript Window that Plays Dailymotion Streaming Video

Tags: javascript, video-streaming

I'm a bit new to Javascript and need some help. I've programmed some basic HTML in the past (many years ago), but a lot of this stuff is new to me. I've tried to read some tutorials and a lot of the information is way over my head. Here is an overview of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Goals

- I have a bunch of streaming videos of my son playing tennis that I'd like to put up on a website. Since the videos were quite large, I signed up for an account on dailymotion cloud so that they could be streamed.
- On a simple webpage, I'd like to list out the date of the match, his opponent and then a hyperlink to the streaming video file.
- Once the hyperlink is clicked, I'd like a javascript pop-up window to be overlaid on top of the existing webpage, and then have the dailymotion video played within.

Here is what I've done so far:

- Contacted Dailymotion Cloud. They told me that they use the Colorbox plugin with jQuery to accomplish this. The user support desk pointed me to this code as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YwhLm/. I really wasn't sure what to do here. So I assumed that I needed to download the jquery and colorbox scripts and use them in conjunction with the sample code.
- I then downloaded jQuery (in particular jquery.min.js) and then uploaded to a folder ~/js on my website
- I went to the colorbox website and downloaded everything. I uploaded the file "jquery.colorbox-min.js" to the same js folder on the root of my website.
- I pasted the code below into the header section of the webpage (I'm having difficulties cutting and pasting here due to formatting issues, but to see the exact code format, click on the jsfiddle URL above):

  ```
  var iframeHtml = '<iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://api.dmcloud.net/player/embed/4bab4364f325e14f14000001/51b871b106361d1359000109?auth=1689337924-0-q4nqc9il-d3e054cef0daa979502cffe4348af0b4" frameborder="0"
  allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  $('#video_link').on('click', function(e) {
      $.colorbox({ 
          'html': iframeHtml,
          'transition': 'none',
          'title': 'My video'
      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
  ```
- I then pasted the following code into the body section of my webpage:

`<a id="video_link" href="#">Video link</a>`

Now the problem is that whenever I do this, I seem to get a lot of errors. The video opens on the main page, instead of opening after clicking the hyperlink. I also see some Javascript code in the background of the page that doesn't seem to have worked.

Can anyone please help? Please take me step by step with what I'm doing wrong. Did I download the wrong versions of colorbox or jquery? Did I put them in the right locations? Is the header coding incorrect? Is the body coding incorrect? Please help.

Thanks